# Laravel: How to show day name from date

Tags: php, laravel

### this code is use for date with day name

```
$month = 12;
$year = 2019;
$dayCount = date('t', strtotime('01-' . $month . '-' . $year));
$days = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++) {
    $tempDate = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $i;
    $days[] = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02s', $year, $month, date('D', strtotime($tempDate)));
}
echo json_encode($days, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sun, Mon, etc. but it has been answered below, thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is what you looking for:

```
<?php
$month = 12;
$year = 2019;

$dayCount = date('t', strtotime('01-'. $month. '-' . $year));

$days = [];

for($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++) {
    $tempDate = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $i;
    $days[] = date('D', strtotime($tempDate));
}

echo json_encode($days);
```

Output:

```
["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun","Mon","Tue"]
```